# AngularJs doubts can you suggest the answer

Tags: stack

what is $sign in angulaJs? and what is difference between the parentscope and isolated scope

Comment: You've got two questions here, and I don't know what you're asking in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your 1st question
$ is meant to be an Angular related Object or Angular "NameSpace" if you will. There are several of them e.g. $scope, $parent etc..

Answer to your 2nd question
Parent scope is just another scope once your have a child scope.

**For example**
You are looping over 2 lists using nested ng-repeat.
The inner ng-repeat will get an isolated scope.
The outter ng-repeat is a parent scope of the inner scope.